# pyqtdeploy : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtdeploy

I have recently updated **pyqtdeploy** to its latest version (3.1.0)

Unfortunately I get an error code that I can't solve.

```
$ pyqtdeploy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergent/.local/bin/pyqtdeploy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sergent/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtdeploy/pyqtdeploy_main.py", line 69, in main
    gui = ProjectGUI(project)
  File "/home/sergent/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtdeploy/gui/project_gui.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._set_project(project)
  File "/home/sergent/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtdeploy/gui/project_gui.py", line 220, in _set_project
    self._name_changed(self._project.name)
  File "/home/sergent/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtdeploy/gui/project_gui.py", line 160, in _name_changed
    title = os.path.basename(name) if name != '' else "Unnamed"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 142, in basename
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
How can I easily fix this problem please ?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version you need to specify a project name e.g.:
pyqtdeploy myproject.pdt
In my case, this leads to a different error, though.
But maybe it is a sufficient solution to your problem.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response. Indeed it was necessary to indicate the name of the project file.
I reported the problem to the developers via the mailing lists https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt.
Since then the problem is fixed in the new snapshots https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/hg/pyqtdeploy.